# Python 3 using word counter to list line & how many times a word appears from an array in file

Tags: python, arrays, counter, python-3.5

So my issue is I've created an array in another script called 'GA' to store the words as eventually it may hold 100+ words. I am trying to then call this array and search for the words in a another txt doc and output how many times each word was found. In the first part of my code 'def ReadFile' I am opening the file cleaning it up and display the lines of which these words are in.

The problem itself is i can't seem to to find a way to display lines with the word as well as output how many times each one was hit, here is my code.

```
 import re
 from collections import Counter
 from Categories.GoingAce import GA

 path = "ChatLogs/Chat1.txt"
 file = path

Lex = Counter(GA)

count = {}

def ReadFile():

    with open(file) as file_read:
        content = file_read.readlines()
        for line in content:
            if any(word in line for word in Lex):
                Cleanse = re.sub('<.*?>', '', line)
                print(Cleanse)

    file_read.close()

def WordCount():

    with open(file) as f:
       Lex = Counter(f.read().split())
    for item in Lex.items(): print ("{}\t{}".format(*item))
    f.close()


#ReadFile()
WordCount()
```

Original Input will look like this

```
<200>   <ilovethaocean> <08/22/06 12:15:36 AM>  hi asl?
<210>   <a_latino_man559>   <08/22/06 12:15:53 AM>  32 m fresno
<210>   <a_latino_man559>   <08/22/06 12:15:53 AM>  u?
<200>   <ilovethaocean> <08/22/06 12:16:12 AM>  "13/f/ca, how r u?"
<200>   <a_latino_man559>   <08/22/06 12:16:18 AM>  13?
```

I then use this to hide everything in brackets:

```
Cleanse = re.sub('<.*?>', '', line)
                    print(Cleanse)
```

Which outputs like this:

hi asl?

32 m fresno

u?

"13/f/ca, how r u?"

13?

Along with that as let's say as an example my GA array contains (hi, u, 13) my perfect aim would be an output like this:

hi appeared 1 time
line_num hi asl?

u appeared 2 time
line_num u?

line_num 13/f/ca, how r u?

etc.

Comment: Can you fix the indentation please?

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with the indention it looks fine?

Comment: Look at your functions, the bodies of both functions aren't indented.

Comment: Done, any chance of helping out with actual issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach with a simplified example:

```
from collections import defaultdict

occurrences = defaultdict(list)
words = ['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'person']

with open(path_to_your_file) as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f.readlines(), start=1):
        for word in words:
            if word in line:
                occurrences[word] += [(i, line)]

for (word, matches) in occurrences.items():
    total_count = sum(line.count(word) for _, line in matches)
    print '%s appeared %d time(s). Line(s):' % (word, total_count)
    print '\n'.join(['\t %d) %s' % (line_num, line.strip()) for line_num, line in matches])
```

Given a text file with the following contents:

```
cat, rat, dog, cat
bird, person
animal
insect
whatever
another bird
etc.
```

The script prints

```
bird appeared 2 time(s). Line(s):
     2) bird, person
     6) another bird
person appeared 1 time(s). Line(s):
     2) bird, person
dog appeared 1 time(s). Line(s):
     1) cat, rat, dog, cat
cat appeared 2 time(s). Line(s):
     1) cat, rat, dog, cat
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution it is partially what i'm looking for but unfortunately i do need it to display the sentence and then just give a total number of how many times each word has appeared at the end or have the two split into different functions as i have attempted

Comment: @Lewis20 can you post a sample cleaned input file contents (so there's no need for me to mess with regexes) with a sample list of words and the expected output? I'll edit my question for your use case then.

Comment: I've added a sample as best i could to explain what i am after

Comment: @Lewis20 see the edited answer that accomplishes what you need with my input.

Comment: using that i receive this output: cam appeard 7 time(s). Line(s):
  0) <200> <ilovethaocean> <08/22/06 12:15:36 AM> hi asl?
  1) <210> <a_latino_man559> <08/22/06 12:15:53 AM> 32 m fresno
  2) <210> <a_latino_man559> <08/22/06 12:15:53 AM> u?
  3) <200> <ilovethaocean> <08/22/06 12:16:12 AM> "13/f/ca, how r u?"
  4) <200> <a_latino_man559> <08/22/06 12:16:18 AM> 13?
  5) <200> <a_latino_man559> <08/22/06 12:16:37 AM> got a cam?
  6) <210> <ilovethaocean> <08/22/06 12:17:08 AM> "naw, mom took it and sold it on ebay coz she said i could get in2 trouble"

Comment: it's on the right track but it's just listing every line

Comment: @Lewis20 can you upload the contents of `chat1.txt` and your `words` list somewhere on pastebin? I'll take a look when I get home in about 8 hours; not sure what the issue is - might be illegal characters or something. In the meantime you can try debugging what's going on with the `matches`.

Comment: Due to the nature of the contents in chat1.txt i cant upload it to anywhere I've already been pushing it by uploading snippets in regards to my word list it just GA = ['hello, cam, face]. I will try just debugging myself for now then, thanks for your help getting to this stage

Comment: Sure, also take a look at what `lines` are, and see what `occurrences['cam']` is. Could be bad characters/line breaks possibly not being treated correctly, etc.